# SWT Resourse Not Properly Disposed - Eclipse Error Log Warning

Tags: eclipse, jar, swt, libraries, windowbuilder

I just installed a couple .jar files to add features to the Eclipse WindowBuilder and for some reason it added a lot of useless toggles under Layout so I deleted them and I have since been getting a warning that my project has errors. I went to the Error Log and got the following message: "Not properly disposed SWT resource". Any help on how to get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code that the message applies to.

Comment: You are not calling `dispose()` on things that need to be disposed when they are done with - things like images, fonts, .... anything that extends `Resource`

Comment: @greg-449 Where do I call dispose? I'm new to this.

Comment: There is no one place, it all depends on what your code is doing and what sort of resources you are using.